# How to clone a div dynamically in Typescript using for loop with incremental ids of cloned divs

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Actually I need to clone the accordion div dynamically using for loop, so that it will clone my accordion at the time of page load .and i need the different ids in incremental counter order on newly cloned divs and there inner divs also should have different ids. Please help me as I am new to Typescript I am not able to do this. I didn't find any attr method to change the ids and any clone method by which we can done cloning in jQuery.

Comment: `TypeScript` is a superset of `JavaScript` you can use it together with `jQuery` or `JavaScript`.

Comment: In jQuery i know how to do it, But i need to do that in typescript. It tried to do that by creating class name public clone(): any { }. but stuck on the step that how change the ids with counter in cloned divs.

Comment: you can just use jquery or do it the angular way.. typescript has nothing to do with it.:)